# How to set 0 when the count row display Null?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, null, ifnull

So, I have this sql:

```
SELECT program.BilanganTerhad - IFNULL(COUNT(daftarprogram.KodProgram), 0) AS kiraan
FROM program, daftarprogram
WHERE program.KodProgram = daftarprogram.KodProgram
  AND daftarprogram.KodProgram = '19'
```

How can I set the null `COUNT()` value to 0? For example: 10 - null = null instead of 10 - 0 = 10.
I need the count become 0, not null.

[This is value from table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjcyQ.png)

[While this is value from table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AO2Ng.png)

[image: table1 full]
[image: table 2]
I want to subtract value from table1 and minus with count(kodprogram)

The thing is I want to subtract value from table1 with count(KodProgram) from table2 based on where condition = KodProgram

Comment: `COUNT()` never returns `NULL`.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  Learn proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT()` never returns `NULL`.  That said, your query is malformed (in addition to using archaic join syntax.  `BilanganTerhad` is in the `SELECT` but it is an aggregation query.

Perhaps you intend:

```
SELECT p.BilanganTerhad - COUNT(*) AS kiraan
FROM program p JOIN
     daftarprogram dp
    ON p.KodProgram = dp.KodProgram 
WHERE dp.KodProgram = '19'
GROUP BY p.BilanganTerhad;
```

Comment: The things is I want to subtract between 2 table.. which is table1.BilanganTerhad - MINUS with COUNT(table2.KodProgram)